# Making personal data in MySQL Database hacker safe?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I'm just starting to build a fairly simple web application where data is stored in a database using php and mysql in one part of the country, and retrieved in another part. The data will contain personal information that must, under no circumstances, be accessed by a third party. And there may be cases where a third party will actively try to access that information. Let's assume its the names of witnesses. This is a system done on a low-budget in a development country without any sort of witness protection.

One of the measures I want to take is to anonymise the data before ever putting it in the database, I'm assuming that's the safest and most low-cost. Besides that, what measures can I take to reduce the chance of hackers getting access to these people's data?

If I use intense encryption on the data before storing it, the people entering it and the ones retrieving it will need to have the encryption key, right? That's an issue since many people will be entering/retrieving data, creating vulnerabilities. If the key is stored on the server, e.g. in the code, it won't be much of a protection, right? Or can the code be made to be fairly hacker-safe?

I read somewhere that someone suggested:

> Webserver<==>Application server ( in DMZ)<==>database server (behind 2nd Firewall) with an application that precludes & prevents SQL injection & similar defenses.
>   In such a scenario, no hacker can get close to the database itself.

Is that true? Would three physical servers be needed for that?

Comment: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: Not sure any server is ever truly "safe." Unless it's powered off and lives at the bottom of an unknown, 500 foot deep hole, encased in concrete.

Comment: Sorry - got to vote to close this too - how to build a secure web app is a HUGE question.

Comment: If the data you have to store is so sensitive, consider hiring someone with more programming experience.

Comment: How it possible that you talked about msyql/php security without mentioning sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

*Can you, the server administrator, sill access the database? If so, then by definition the setup should be considered unsafe.*

Definitely use the obvious techniques such as SSL, of course, as that pretty much prevents man-in-the-middle attacks. Carefully program your application to avoid SQL injections and that stuff.

If one of the layers (say the webserver) is cracked, then from that layer requests can be made to a layer below that, etc. A layered model isn't safe by definition, it just takes a few extra steps.